# Resizing div to background image set to contain

Tags: html, dynamic, height, background-image

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I have a div with a large background image.  The BG image is set to contain so it will expand and contract with browser size.  The issue I'm having is if you shrink the browser, the div still shows the height to 1000px.  So while the image expands properly to fit, if you begin to scroll down you see the large gap that now occupies the 1000px height under the picture where the body bg color comes through (since the picture has shrunk via the contain).  How can I make it so the div moves up and the gap disappears?  I have seen this done on several sites.

CSS Code:

```
.contain { background-size: contain; }
.mainsplashtop {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background-image:url(../images/main_splash.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top:0;

}
```

HTML

```
<div data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" class="mainsplashtop contain"><a class="scroll" href="#destination1"></a></div>
```

You can see what I mean on the site (please disregard the disaray as its still in early development)

www.doyouhaveasaddle.com

Here are examples of what im trying to achieve.
http://www.unbornink.com/
http://www.fmolinari.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could use media queries but was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Supporting dog breeders? :(

Comment: Perhaps you should read the site closer.  I support rescues and only reputable show breeders.  There is even an entire section on rescues and their contact info.